# Assembly programming input+5

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have this question. When studying assembler in depth, I encountered such a problem! We all know the standard conversion from a number to a string in order to output a number.

`mov bx,input+5
    mov cx,0
    mov x,si
nextd: 
    mov dx,0 
    mov di,10
    div di 
    add dl,48
    dec bx
    mov [bx],dl
    inc cx
    cmp ax,0
    jne nextd`

Why do we write +5 in the first line? Why don't we put the length of the string in that case, or the length of the register itself? I don't understand why +5

Comment: Because the digits are produced backwards (least significant digit first) but humans write them forwards (most significant digit first). A 16 bit number in decimal is at most 5 digits hence the `+5`. Notice the `dec bx`.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) shows a C version of this loop with explanation of decrementing from the end of a buffer.

Comment: Is `mov x,si` supposed to be `mov ax, si`?  Otherwise this makes no sense.  (Or storing SI to memory is just something unrelated, and AX already holds the number.) 
 Also, use triple backticks for a multi-line code *block*